# Swift3 NSApplicationMainについて

Tags: swift, python, xcode, swift3

Swift3でpythonを呼び出そうと思い以下のサイトを参考にしました。
https://github.com/ndevenish/Site-ndevenish/blob/master/_posts/2016-06-20-using-python-with-swift.markdown

```
import Cocoa

NSApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv)
```

の"Process.argc"で　Type'Process'has no member'argc'とエラーを吐きます。
助けてください。
説明ではmain.swiftファイルを作成して上記のコードを書くだけのことでした。

Answer (score 1):

掲載リンクの記事は日付が2016-06-20とありますから、まだSwift 3の正式版がリリースされる前の記事のようです。Swift3版へのリンクがうまく埋めこまれていませんが、[こちら](https://github.com/ndevenish/Site-ndevenish/blob/master/_posts/2017-04-11-using-python-with-swift-3.markdown)だと思われます。

そちらの記事中ではこのようなコードになっています。

```
import Cocoa

exit(NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv))
```

Swift Standard Libraryの`Process`クラスはSwift 3で`CommandLine`に名称が変わりました。

[CommandLine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/commandline)

記事内容の詳細までは読んでいないので、なぜ`exit()`で囲む必要があったのかまではよくわかりませんが。

Swift3まではバージョンによる変更点がかなり大きいので、ネット上でSwiftの記事を参考にされる場合には、十分注意された方がいいでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflowに[似たような質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009050/how-do-i-access-program-arguments-in-swift)がありました。

[Process](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process)には`argc`は無く、`arguments`で参照するようです。
[CommandLine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/commandline)には`argc`がありますね。

StackOverflowでの質問によると`CommandLine`はSwift2の頃は`Process`と呼ばれていたようなので、参考にされているURLでの`Process.argc`の記載は単純に更新漏れでは無いでしょうか。
参考先のGitHubで「ミスがあります」と指摘してあげると喜ばれるかもしれません。